# What is the java equivalent to javascript's String.fromCharCode?

Tags: java, javascript

What it the java equivalent of javascript's:

```
String.fromCharCode(n1, n2, ..., nX)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromCharCode.asp

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That would be something like as follows:

```
public static String fromCharCode(int... codePoints) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(codePoints.length);
    for (int codePoint : codePoints) {
        builder.append(Character.toChars(codePoint));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Note that casting to `char` isn't guaranteed to work because the codepoint value might exceed the upper limit of `char` (65535). The `char` was established in the dark Java ages when [Unicode 3.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) wasn't out yet which goes beyond 65535 characters.

**Update**: the `String` has actually [a constructor taking an `int[]`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28int[],%20int,%20int%29) (introduced since Java 1.5, didn't knew it from top of head), which handles this issue correctly. The above could be simplified as follows:

```
public static String fromCharCode(int... codePoints) {
    return new String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.length);
}
```

Comment: +1 for Unicode perfection, but I doubt the Javascript function can correctly handle codepoints bigger than 65536.

Comment: This appears to work for most values.  I am trying:
new String(new int[]{141}, 0, 1) which in javascript prints, "?" but in java does not.  Is 141 invalid?  I am trying to debug some obfuscation code I ported from Javascript to Java and am getting inconsistent results for some characters.

Comment: That's dependent on the character encoding which is a completely different story. The JS environment is apparenly using a different character encoding than Java environment. At least, the above should work flawlessly for an Unicode character encoding like UTF-8.